# Can't locate DBI.pm in @INC can't resolve

Tags: linux, perl, ubuntu

The error says:

```
Can't locate DBI.pm in @INC (@INC contains
    /etc/perl 
    /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 
    /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 
    /usr/lib/perl5 
    /usr/share/perl5 
    /usr/lib/perl/5.14 
    /usr/share/perl/5.14 
    /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/helloworld.pl line 7.
```

But I already added the path of my module to environment variable using

```
export PERL5LIB=/home/vagrant/perl5/lib/perl5/i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int
```

When I checked using `perl -V` it is included already, see the following:

```
%ENV:
    PERL5LIB="/home/vagrant/perl5/lib/perl5"
    PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="/home/vagrant/perl5"
    PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base "/home/vagrant/perl5""
    PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/home/vagrant/perl5"
  @INC:
    /home/vagrant/perl5/lib/perl5/5.14.2/i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int
    /home/vagrant/perl5/lib/perl5/5.14.2
    /home/vagrant/perl5/lib/perl5/i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int <--- My module
    /home/vagrant/perl5/lib/perl5
    /etc/perl
    /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2
    /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2
    /usr/lib/perl5
    /usr/share/perl5
    /usr/lib/perl/5.14
    /usr/share/perl/5.14
    /usr/local/lib/site_perl
```

My machine is `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS`

Your help is much appreciated, thank you guys!

Comment: You are running a different copy of perl when you test your code from the one you run with `perl -V`. How do you test your code? What does `which -a perl` show? What is in the shebang line of your program?

Comment: Did you actually install the DBI module?

Comment: I tested it via http request in browser, the result of `which -a perl` is `/usr/bin/perl`, see my test code: #!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text\html \n\n";

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

print "Hello World\n";

Comment: Yes i installed it and that `DBI.pm` and its pre-requisite modules are located in my module.

Comment: See the results: `vagrant@precise32:~$ ls /home/vagrant/perl5/lib/perl5/i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int

auto  Bundle  DBD  DBI  DBI.pm  dbixs_rev.pl  perllocal.pod  Storable.pm  Win32`

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Re "*But I already added the path of my module to environment variable*", No, you didn't. You only showed that you added it to the environment of a different `perl` process; you didn't add it to the environment of the `perl` process that's giving you the error.

Comment: I could also be a permission issue. I think directories in PERL5LIB to which you do not have access won't be added to `@INC`.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for 'use lib' [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) and 'perl run' [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) and Ubuntu environment variables [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).

I suspect you're running the script from different environments.  Your shell prompt is a different environment from what an httpd server would use, which is also different from what the cron program would use.  When you add an environment variable to your environment, it's only in your environment (and often just that *instance* of your environment) and not those others.  Those other applications can not see or read your environment variables.

I'm guessing here as you didn't supply any code, that adding the following lines to your script, just before 'use DBI' *may* help you:

```
use lib "/home/vagrant/perl5/lib/perl5";
use lib "/home/vagrant/perl5/lib/perl5/i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int";
```

I say *may* because, as the great ikegami pointed out, if this separate applications' environment does not have access to your directories, then it won't add those folders to the @INC list.  The first section of output you posted clearly shows that your home folders are not in the list.